# Collection before hook called twice

Tags: meteor

I am using matb33:collection-hooks

I have difficulties to understand why the versions.insert is called one time (only one console log is displayed) but there is 2 records with 2 different _id inserted in the versions collection.

```
Requirements = new Meteor.Collection('requirements');
var versions = new Meteor.Collection('requirements_versions');

Requirements.before.update(function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {

  // copy doc to versions collection
  var savedDoc = _.extend({}, doc); // shallow copy
  if(typeof(savedDoc._id) != 'undefined') delete savedDoc._id;

  console.log(versions.insert(savedDoc)); // FIXME: why inserted 2 times ???
});
```

If I add a return false at the end of the hook, the record is inserted only once, but of course the original requirement update is not called.

Comment: Possibly a client + server duplication. What context is this code running in, client or server?

Comment: I just had the same issue.  My `Collection.after.update` hooks have `DifferentCollection.updates(id, {$inc:...` in them and they were getting called twice. The documentation says it "works across client, server, or mix"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by omitting `_id`

```
const versions = new Meteor.Collection('requirements_versions'); 
const Requirements = new Meteor.Collection('requirements');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Requirements.before.update(function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {

        // insert version doc
        versions.insert(_.omit(doc, '_id'));
    });
}
```